# How do I capture all complying values using a mask in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, boolean-indexing

Value_counts performed in one specific data frame column shows visually that there are 441 values lower than 10. When I run a mask (boolean indexing) in order to access those values it only gets 12 of the 441.

I thought it was a datatype issue. However, right before the operations above I changed the column data type to float using the astype function. There should not be an issue with data type.

Comment: Can you please provide us with a sample data similar to what you're dealing with?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fuFEIKSohXGKQWLLq9zeXRtVXVlzwlDG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ptdiYzF6W5I1S3e1FFSlCGxNfjT-t9Jk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. A little explanation or creating a small sample data, and also your expected output would help a lot!

Comment: Thanks!. Here is the data https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cgo9Y9FPUGAhUpMzat-inH_zP54PFpQ7

Comment: I am trying to capture all rating_numerator values below 10...It shows 441 (visually) in the value_counts but using the mask <'10' it only captures 12 corresponding to 1, 0 and 007.

Answer (score 0):

I used the function astype(float) all along for masking and value_counts operations. This catches all the numeric values complying the filter and not only a few str values present in the data.